# Weird Python subprocess hang

Tags: python, windows-xp, python-3.3

I have an infinite loop that does this:

```
 print("text for debugging my issue1")
 execution=["python", "-u", mainScript, directory, folder, cardIP]
 _,_=subprocess.Popen(execution, shell=True).communicate()
```

and in `MainScript`, the first line is:

```
print("text for debugging my issue2")
```

and after that line, I am just printing a lot of stuff. (in `MainScript`)

Now, my problem is that most of the time it works fine, I can see printed:

```
"text for debugging my issue1"
"text for debugging my issue2"
 [data printed in 'MainScript']
```

but sometimes, it gets stuck in `_,_=subprocess.Popen(execution, shell=True).communicate()`, means I see:

```
"text for debugging my issue1"
"text for debugging my issue2"
 [data printed in 'MainScript']
"text for debugging my issue1"
"text for debugging my issue2"
 [data printed in 'MainScript']
"text for debugging my issue1"
  ///Missing "text for debugging my issue2" here and all of 'MainScrip' output,
  ///Here it just stop working.
```

It just hangs.  When I press any key, it immediately continue to work, printing all the stuff and the program is running from where it stopped.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple script as your main script? Try to remove any variable while debugging. It might be your script that is causing what you see.

Comment: I did try it. the problem is that I need to test it many times, it happens like in 1\5 of the times so even to check it with a simple script is not a fool proof. And also, what else can be be reason for this function to hang beside itself? (its code)

Comment: I can see that not many people encountered this problem, I'll try to check the subprocess.py module

Comment: another related question: "Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited." this is about the communicate() function that was discussed in stack overflow many. But not this question - If I use the unbuffered python ('python -u') will it make it be unbuffered?